# replace string of json with another string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string which is

I got this string by converting

```
var json = org.cometd.JSON.toJSON(envelope.messages);

"[{\"version\": \"1.0\", \"minimumVersion\": \"0.9\", \"channel\": \"/meta/handshake\", \"supportedConnectionTypes\": [\"long-polling\", \"callback-polling\"], \"advice\": {\"timeout\": 60000, \"interval\": 0}, \"id\": \"1\"}]"
```

and I need to replace some symbols, I need output like that

```
[{"version":"1.0","minimumVersion":"0.9","channel":"/meta/handshake","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling"],"advice":{"timeout":60000,"interval":0},"id":"1"}]
```

means symbols to be replaced are  `\\` with `""` and   `"[` with `[`  and  `]"` with `]`

Help me if posible.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple use `Json.Parse()`

```
var json = "[{\"version\": \"1.0\", \"minimumVersion\": \"0.9\", \"channel\": \"/meta/handshake\", \"supportedConnectionTypes\": [\"long-polling\", \"callback-polling\"], \"advice\": {\"timeout\": 60000, \"interval\": 0}, \"id\": \"1\"}]"

JSON.Parse(json);
```

Comment: not working :(    

var json = org.cometd.JSON.toJSON(envelope.messages);
     JSON.Parse(json);
     alert(json);

Comment: if you alert its result you will get [object obejct'  check by logging it using console.log

Comment: why you are alerting your json? and if possible create your fiddle so that I can update that ....!!

Comment: var json = org.cometd.JSON.toJSON(envelope.messages);
     JSON.Parse(json);
        _webSocket.send(json);
        this._debug('Transport', this.getType(), 'sent', envelope, 'metaConnect =', metaConnect);

        // Manage the timeout waiting for the response
        var maxDelay = this.getConfiguration().maxNetworkDelay;
        var delay = maxDelay;
        if (metaConnect)
        {
            delay += this.getAdvice().timeout;
            _connected = true;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
json.replace('\\', '')
```

There are no `"[` in the string itself, there's just `"` that define the string.

Comment: and also in the starting and ending i wants to remove " this symbol

Comment: @krishan what is your goal exactly?

Comment: replaced are \\ with "" and "[ with [ and ]" with ]

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `replace function`

```
mystring.replace(/\\/g,'').replace(/" "[ "/g,'"["')
```